# C ints are being changed into large numbers

Tags: c, int

I have a program that reads data from a text file and puts the data into a structure to make a "person". All works apart from the integers that get read are not the correct value. They come out as very large numbers.
Thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "structs.h"

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char userInput = ' ';
    struct strPerson people[1];
    int i;
    int aPeople = 2;
    int menuSelect;


    while (fp == NULL) 
    {
        fp = fopen("test", "r"); // Open File To Read
        if (fp == NULL) 
        {
            perror("Error While Loading File\n");
        }
        else
        {

            for(i = 0; i < aPeople; i++)
            {
                fscanf(fp, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", 
                        people[i].perSurname,
                        people[i].perForname1,
                        people[i].perForname2,
                        people[i].perGender,
                        people[i].perUni.perAwardTitle,
                        people[i].perHomeAddress.perHAddress1,
                        people[i].perHomeAddress.perHAddress2,
                        people[i].perHomeAddress.perHAddress3,
                        people[i].perHomeAddress.perHAddress4,
                        people[i].perLocalAddress.perHAddress1,
                        people[i].perLocalAddress.perHAddress2,
                        people[i].perLocalAddress.perHAddress3,
                        people[i].perLocalAddress.perHAddress4,
                        people[i].perUni.perDOE.nDay,
                        people[i].perUni.perDOE.nMonth,
                        people[i].perUni.perDOE.nYear,
                        people[i].perUni.perDOG.nDay,
                        people[i].perUni.perDOG.nMonth,
                        people[i].perUni.perDOG.nYear,
                        people[i].perUni.perRegNumber,
                        people[i].strDOB.nDay,
                        people[i].strDOB.nMonth,
                        people[i].strDOB.nYear);
            }


            system("clear");
        }
    }

    while (userInput != 'g') 
    {   
        system("clear");
        printf("          |User System|\n"
                "|------------------------------|\n"
                "|------------------------------|\n"
                "|A) Save Current Data To A File|\n"
                "|B) Enter Details              |\n"
                "|C) View Details               |\n"
                "|D) Amend Details              |\n"
                "|E) Search by Award Title      |\n"
                "|F) Search by Surname          |\n"
                "|G) Shut Down                  |\n"
                "|------------------------------|\n");
        printf("Enter Function: ");

        userInput = getchar();
        getchar();

        if (userInput == 'c')
        {
            for(i = 0; i < aPeople; i++)
            {
                printf("%d) %s %s\n", i + 1, people[i].perForname1, people[i].perSurname);
            }
            printf("Select Person To View Details: ");
            scanf("%d", &menuSelect);
            getchar();



                printf("Name: %s %s %s\n",people[menuSelect-1].perForname1,
                                          people[menuSelect-1].perForname2,
                                          people[menuSelect-1].perSurname);
                printf("DOB: %d %d %d\n", people[menuSelect-1].strDOB.nDay,
                                          people[menuSelect-1].strDOB.nMonth,
                                          people[menuSelect-1].strDOB.nYear);

            getchar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `struct strPerson people[1];` is an array with a __single__ element but you are trying to read 2 records, which will trash memory past the end of the array.

Comment: @user3121023 thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the definition of `struct strPerson`.

Yet it is obvious that you are not passing the address of the integers you attempt to parse with `fscanf`.  This invokes undefined behaviour, and it is quite surprising that your program actually runs at all.

You should compile with warnings enabled to detect such common mistakes: `gcc -Wall -W -Werror` is your friend.

Furthermore, you should test the return value of `fscanf` to verify how many fields have been parsed.  Any field not parsed has an indeterminate value.

Also you are attempting to parse 2 structures, but the array of structures only has 1 entry.